# android apk map manager "waiting for map list"

Tags: ros, android-core, ros-kinetic, rosjava, 2d-nav-goal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Can you help me please?
I'm using the rosjava map manager tutorial (in this link https://github.com/DreamFly111/make_a_map ), i've installed the apk file and i'm able to connect with my robot. but after the master connection, i have a waiting dialog with message "waiting for maps" like it's waiting for somethings, the "Make A Map" tutorial is working fine, but the "Map Nav" tutorial show the same waiting dialog with the message "Waiting for map List", i dont why. I have been working with rosjava for 3 month but i admit there are many things i still don't understand don't know what to do. Thanks you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301689/android-apk-map-manager-%22waiting-for-map-list%22/) by [Douma](https://answers.ros.org/users/37194/douma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just for the record in case anyone has the same problem, here's an answer for the question: https://github.com/rosjava/android_apps/issues/79. Note that there's some work to be done to make this work.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2018-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0